# Сайт начинает моргать сайт при скролле

Tags: html, css, загрузка

Есть сайт http://avoska.github.io/metall/, загружается нормально, отображается вроде тоже, но как только начинаешь его скроллить вверх-низ он начинает моргать.
В консоли выделил эти запросы, ничего не показало...
[image]

Что это может быть и как это пофиксить?!

Comment: у меня ни чего не моргает

Comment: @Дима-Свободин Тоже все плавно

Comment: есть такое, разберитесь с js, что, как и при каких обстоятельствах показываете/скрываете, возможно где то что то провтикали

Comment: [скрин](http://i.imgur.com/5AYb3xa.png) [еще один](http://i.imgur.com/5AYb3xa.png) скинул знакомому у него тоже моргает :S

Comment: @LenovoID, там жесть с перерисовкой... Совсем жесть... В новом хроме... Но не уверен, что можно что-то адекватное посоветовать...